# Possibly a Pointer Problem in C

Tags: c++, c

I am not sure why the following code fragement is not doing what it is supposed to
do. Returning the numbers 0 to 9 in the second loop would be idea. *scp is a pointer
to a memory region allocated to the program.

```
 unsigned char* scp = (unsigned char*)(0x8e000000);
 scp_size = 10;
 for(i = 0; i < scp_size; i++, scp++) {
  *scp = i;
  } 
 }

   scp = (unsigned char*)(0x8e000000);
   for(i = 0; i < scp_size; i++, scp++) {
        printf("Data read[%d]: %d\n", i, *scp); 
 }
```

The acual output is however completely different:

```
 [exec] Data read[0]: 3
 [exec] 
 [exec] Data read[1]: 3
 [exec] 
 [exec] Data read[2]: 3
 [exec] 
 [exec] Data read[3]: 3
 [exec] 
 [exec] Data read[4]: 128
 [exec] 
 [exec] Data read[5]: 35
 [exec] 
 [exec] Data read[6]: 32
 [exec] 
 [exec] Data read[7]: 1
 [exec] 
 [exec] Data read[8]: 18
 [exec] 
 [exec] Data read[9]: 146
```

Anybody an idea if I mixed here something up with the pointer or any other idea what might have gone wrong? Many thanks

Comment: Your code, as it stands, doesn't compile. What is the actual compiling code?

Comment: Address 0x8e000000 contains shared memory, where I can write data to and read from. This is probably worth having a look if the MMU needs to be turned off...

Comment: How are you allocating the memory at the address you're referencing? Why don't you have 

    unsigned char* scp = (unsigned char*)malloc(10)? 

You've omitted the declaration of i. What type is it declared as? The printf statement is very particular about the types you pass in for its format specifiers.

You're assuming an unsigned char is one byte in this code (and it probably is) but, as a good practice, you should be incrementing by sizeof(unsigned char).

Comment: does it require special hardware? As I am getting seg-fault with this particular address.

Comment: What is the OS? You might want to cast *scp to (int) before printing it with "%d".

Comment: You definitely need to tell us the platform (processor family, OS, is this code in a kernel driver or user application).

Comment: Simplify the problem. Your code does not appear to be broken. Can you write and read back a single character? Is 0x8e000000 a memory or is it a device of some sort?

Answer (score 6):

The code as you posted it is right. The problem is not here.

There is a problem with the special memory region that you are writing to. Either it is read-only, or can't be written directly, or something in this way. Maybe someone can help you further if you tell us the platform that is running this code.

As @Jari pointed out, it will be cleaner if you used array access.

Answer (score 3):

Your format specification to `printf` doesn't match the types you actually pass into it, so all bets are off. `scp` is a pointer to unsigned character, but you give `printf` a `%d` format specifier, which means integer. Since `printf` takes varargs, the compiler can't auto-promote `*scp` to int. Effectively (on 32-bit integer systems), it's reading your character and three garbage bytes and interpreting that as an integer, then printing that value.

Try `printf("Data read[%d]: %d\n", i, static_cast<int>(*scp));`

All that being said, you can't just write to arbitrary memory address like that. To allocate memory use:
`unsigned char* scp = new unsigned char*[10];`

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned char arr[10];
    unsigned char* scp = arr;
    int scp_size = 10;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < scp_size; i++, scp++) {
        *scp = i;
    } 

    scp = arr;
    for(i = 0; i < scp_size; i++, scp++) {
        printf("Data read[%d]: %d\n", i, *scp); 
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

Is the memory being changed between the write and the read?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you are not using array access to the memory are pointed to by scp? I was thinking something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < scp_size; i++) {
    scp[i] = i;
} 

for(i = 0; i < scp_size; i++) {
    printf("Data read[%d]: %d\n", i, scp[i]); 
}
```

Comment: The reason for that is, that the memory location is fixed at 0x8e000000 where I want to write too. Else this makes of course sense Jari ;)

Comment: Jari's example does in fact operate on 0x8e000000 if that is where scp is pointing.

Comment: I still don't see the difference of using *scp and scp[i], although that might not be the problem in your code.

Comment: There is no difference, for built-in types.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are running in user mode, where pointers are virtual addresses.  But your 0x8e000000 is a physical address.  You can't just "turn off" the MMU without disrupting every other piece of code running on the machine, you need to find your OS's kernel call for creating a virtual mapping to a particular physical address space.  On Linux, you could probably mmap `/dev/mem` or /dev/kmem` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like it should work to me (though I would have used an array). I'd try stepping through it with a debugger and watching what happens to the memory or setting watchpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that one of two things is happening:

Perhaps the printf in the second loop may be misinterpreting the third parameger (*scp). Remember that printf isn't type-safe. *scp may be being interpreted as an int because you are using the %d format specifier - there doesn't appear to be a format specifier for unsigned char. Try this:

```
scp = (unsigned char*)(0x8e000000);
for(i = 0; i < scp_size; i++, scp++) {
    int val = *scp;
    printf("Data read[%d]: %d\n", i, val); 
}
```

Alternatively the contents of the memory block is being changed between your writing to it and reading it. Is it shared memory that is written to by another process/thread/t, or some kind of device-mapped buffer? Can you remove the possibility that another process or device is writing to it?

Comment: Shouldn't the int val = *scp; declaration be outside the for loop?

Comment: @Tangrs  No, for each interation my suggestion is to _explicitly_ convert *scp to an int, and then print it, rather than assuming that printf will do the conversion correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the memory area is not writable?

came across below. this should help:-

Explore the memory management capabilities and/or the memory map of your
hardware, and/or your OS, and/or your system monitor.

If you can represent a value that is guaranteed to be a specific memory
address as constrained by your system, as a C pointer, than you can do
what you suggest. You may be forced to do this in assembly, and even
then, on many operating systems, you have to build something like a
kernel driver in order to allocate anything other than virtual memory.

That said, memory mapped I/O is still quite common. but memory-mapped
I/O bound to a specific hardware address space is really not something
you can talk about strictly in the context of C. This is a question for
comp.arch, or for some forum devoted to your hardware or OS platform.

There are linux kernel drivers that deal with memory-mapped I/O in all
kinds of devices, and might not be too hard to analyze. I'd look at
some of the ISA drive controllers or old sound cards for likely places
to find examples (but I am just guessing).

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to do what you are doing with 0x8e00... unless you have a specific reason such as it is memory mapped IO register or something. You need to tell us what in the world you are trying to do first; at first glance this is bad code, you are mixing types, grabbing what looks to be random memory locations, etc.

Answer (score -1):

If I assume the loop variable i is an int, then at every step you are writing an integer (i) starting at 0x8e000000 (which takes up sizeof(int) number of bytes) and incrementing scp by sizeof(unsigned char) number of bytes. Since the size of an int and a char (4 and 1 on most systems) is different, scp++ is not advancing your pointer by the correct number of bytes. So the next time round you do an *scp = i, you are overwriting the previous integer the 3rd byte onwards.

Comment: If this was the problem, shouldn't the behaviour be different? Either all printed values should be 0 (on a big endian system) or the values should be be printed as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, as intended (on a little endian system).

Comment: I don't think that your answer is correct. The OP isn't writing ints to the memory block. To do that would require that scp be of type int*. The line '*scp = i;' converts the integer value of i to an unsigned char and writes it (as an unsigned char) to the address pointed to by scp. What you are saying would require something like '*(int*)scp = i;'.

Comment: No, `*scp = i` will truncate the integer value to a char and only write one byte.

Comment: Well, I probably added more confusion with my comment. The OP should skip over this section and get on with the other answers. 

And thanks everybody for explaining it. So am I right if I say that when we have a similar situation when we assign a double to an int and the double gets truncated to the shorter value?